# Handling different responses in ajax success callback

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a record of a users details on a page, and a modal dialog with a form to update the details. When the modal dialog is submitted the contents of its form is sent to the server through an ajax request.

The server validates the data received from the ajax request. If validation fails it returns the reasons for this failure to be appended to the modal dialog. If validation succeeds the update is made and a html table of the new details is returned and .html(data) is used to replace the old data.

Using the ajax success callback how is it possible to work out if the data returned is validation errors or a table of user data after a successful update?

Comment: You need to either use an HTTP response code and check it, possibly using a `failure` handler, or return JSON back with appropriate success/failure data, or peek inside the HTML and guess which scenario happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error function fires when a non-http 200 response code is issued back in the response. Even if your data has erroneous validation logic chances are the result is still going to come back as 200 or success because the ajax request was responded to with no error.

Be careful if you change the http status to reflect your own error checking because you are really misusing the status at that point.

For hard errors, such as when no database connection could be made, it is ok to return 500 which would cause the ajax error function to fire.

However, in your case I would send a flag back with a data such as

```
successFunction(data)
{
    if (data.Success)
       someElement.html(data.HtmlContent)
    else
       someError.html(data.Errors)
}
```

I am not familiar with php. I do know there are many php/MVC frameworks that support a structured way to do this. If I were you, I would look around and find a popular php/mvc framework and start learning how they do it.

[Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ajaxservice/index.html) is a link that I found that seems to be a solution to your very problem.

Comment: This is exactly how I was thinking thanks! Although how do I send a flag with the response from the server? (Using php)

Comment: Added a link illustrating how to return a data "Model".